# Jquery on hover html text change

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I have a button like below.
I have a list of buttons.
When user clicks it, I run a javascript function and it makes an ajax request, if request response is success, then I change status attribute of button tag. I change it from 1 to 2.

When the attribute status=1, I want user to see some text when hovering on button.

When the attribute status=2, I don't want him to see anything on button hover.

I tried like below but after status=2, still button text changes on hover.
How can i fix this?

```
<button onclick="dosomething()" id="someid" status="1">name</button>

<script>
function dosomething(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"somefile.php",
        success : function(data) {
            if (data == '200') {
                $('#someid').attr('status', '2');
            }
        },
        error : function() {
            alert('error');
        },
    })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    updateHoverStates()
});

$(document).change(function () {
    updateHoverStates()
});

function updateHoverStates() {
    $('button[status=1]').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).text('You are hovering');
        },
        function () {
            $(this).text('You are not hovering');
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should really be setting your click handler in the javascript; additionally, all of your jQuery should be inside `$(document).ready(...)`. This code is a real mess.

Comment: I think its better to use css class instead of `status` attribute to keep your html valid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may work, that way the event is checking the staus attr each time it is called, instead of just once at bind time.

```
function updateHoverStates() {
    $('button[status]').hover(
        function () {
            if($(this).attr('status') == '1')
                $(this).text('You are hovering');
        },
        function () {
            if($(this).attr('status') == '1')
                $(this).text('You are not hovering');
        }
    );
}
```

As a side note, I believe `data-status` would be a better supported way of having custom attributes, this also would allow the use of `.data('status')` instead of `.attr('status')`.

Alternatively you may be able to use CSS to simulate that

```
button[status="1"]:hover {
    //possible attributes here
}
```

Comment: I suppose this spends more calculation time. But this worked as i wanted :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ajzsv/20/

```
<button onclick="dosomething()" id="someid" status="1">name</button>

<script>
function dosomething()
{
    $('#someid').attr('status', '2');
    $('#someid').unbind('hover');
}

$(document).ready( function()
{
    $('button').each( function()
    {
        $(this).hover(
        function ()
        {
            $(this).text('You are hovering');
        },
        function ()
        {
            $(this).text('You are not hovering');
        });
    });
});
</script>​
```

Answer (score 0):

`change` events don't bubble up to the document, so `updateHoverStates` is probably not being called a second time.

Comment: what about using stop() then live() or toggle()? Can you toggle an on hover event and set the attribute differently each time, therefore, changing the text on the button?

Answer (score 0):

You once set the hover function for all buttons that matched the selector `button[status=1]`. You changed the `status` attribute later, but that doesn't detach the hover event listeners from those buttons.

In the function where you set

```
$('#someid').attr('status', '2');
```

you should simply remove the event listener manually.

```
$('#someid').unbind('hover');
```

Comment: Thank you but i don't prefer to unbind hover because after changing status attribute i use another hover function.